# Identity matrix

Tags: python, python-2.x

As I was learning python, I encountered a problem and have been unable to identify what went wrong. Please look at the python code below.

```
def is_identity_matrix(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    if n != len(matrix[0]):
        return False
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        j = 0
        while j < n:
            if matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][i]:
                if matrix[i][j] != 1:
                    return False
            else:
                if matrix[i][j] != 0:
                    return False
            j+=1
        i+=1
    return True

matrix6 = [[1,0,0,0],  
           [0,1,0,1],  
           [0,0,1,0],  
           [0,0,0,1]]

print is_identity_matrix(matrix6)
```

This outputs `True` instead of `False` as the question is asking for us to check for identity matrix where only the diagonal line in the middle should have 1, the rest should be 0. Since `matrix[1][3]` is not equal to 1, the output should be false. Can anybody help? Thank you so much!

Comment: shouldn't your `if matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][i]:` be `if i == j:`? and `for i in range(n):` is more pythonic than the `while` variant...

Comment: got it. This is illuminating. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should compare `i == j` instead of `matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][i]`.

and here the version using `for` instead of `while`.

```
def is_identity_matrix(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    if n != len(matrix[0]):
        return False
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i == j:
                if matrix[i][j] != 1:
                    return False
            else:
                if matrix[i][j] != 0:
                    return False
    return True
```

or even (using `product` from `itertools`) which saves an indentation level and looks even more readable to me:

```
from itertools import product

def is_identity_matrix(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    if n != len(matrix[0]):
        return False
    for i, j in product(range(n), range(n)):
        if i == j:
            if matrix[i][j] != 1:
                return False
        else:
            if matrix[i][j] != 0:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: In this case, the `[i]` and `[j]` will auto increase due to each run of `for`?

Comment: `i` (and `j`, respectively) will iterate through all the integers from `0` to `n-1` - this does exactly what your `while` construct did. it's just more compact and feels much more natural to me. you could even compactify it  more and use `for i, j in product(range(n), range(n)):` (you'd have to `from itertools import product` first).

Comment: Thank you for showing me this. I went to read up about 'range()' too. Thanks!

Comment: added the `product` version in my answer; just in case that's interesting for you...

Comment: Basically just `all(matrix[i][j]==(i==j) for i in range(n) for j in range(n))`

Comment: whoa! that's a nice one-liner for that! did not think of that. this is nice abuse of `True==1` and `False==0`.

Comment: i just got schooled too... that's how your skills improve. good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Like hiro protagonist said, the problem is in the line:

```
if matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][i]:
```

You are checking if the value of a cell matches the value on the diagonal, where I assume you want to check if you are on or off the diagonal.

The line should read:

```
if i == j:
```

Answer (score -1):

if you have not learned range(), just  like me now, 
here is my solution:

```
def is_identity_matrix(matrix):
    #Write your code here
    n=len(matrix)
    if n==len(matrix[0]):
        i=0
        while i<n:
            j=0
            while j<n:
                if j==i:
                    if matrix[i][j]!=1:
                        return False
                else:
                    if matrix[i][j]!=0 or matrix[j][i]!=0:
                        return False
                j=j+1
            i=i+1
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```